# why not show text when calling api in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

when calling api returns only red background but not text
I expect the api to return a list of movies displayed on the app interface

but when i return the Items function directly inside the render function, it returns me the text, but when I call the function outside, it just doesn't return the text but just the background

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Axios from 'axios';
export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then(({data}) => {
        setData(data.movies);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
  const Items = item => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'blue'}}>
          {item.title}, {item.releaseYear}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 24}}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            return index.toString();
          }}`enter code here`
          renderItem={Items}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Items` component likewise :

```
  const Items = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'blue'}}>
          {item.title}, {item.releaseYear}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, and I ran successfully

Comment: Good to hear, Keep learning